# Thread blocking Kafka Coordinators in Akka-streams-kafka

Tags: multithreading, scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream

Im using VisualVM to profile an application that uses akka-streams-kafka.

It shows a lot of Kafka coordinator blocking threads
[image: It shows a lot of Kafka coordinator blocking threads]

Who are these coordinators?

I also have three Kafka consumers that are also blocking threads
[image: I also have three Kafka consumers that are also blocking threads]

Do I need to create a separate Execution context for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Java Kafka client [API](http://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)

> 1. One Consumer Per Thread A simple option is to give each thread its own consumer instance. Here are the pros and cons of this approach:
>      PRO: It is the easiest to implement PRO: It is often the fastest as no
>      inter-thread co-ordination is needed PRO: It makes in-order processing
>      on a per-partition basis very easy to implement (each thread just
>      processes messages in the order it receives them). CON: More consumers
>      means more TCP connections to the cluster (one per thread). In general
>      Kafka handles connections very efficiently so this is generally a
>      small cost. CON: Multiple consumers means more requests being sent to
>      the server and slightly less batching of data which can cause some
>      drop in I/O throughput. CON: The number of total threads across all
>      processes will be limited by the total number of partitions.